# create column name repeats for column values when particular columns have duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot

I have a dataframe that I need to spin around (am not sure if this involves stacking or pivoting..)

So, where I have duplicate values in columns "Year", "Month and "Group" , I want to shift the follow columns names to be repeated for the Variable

So if this is the original DF:

```
Year  Month  Group  Variable  feature1  feature2  feature3  
2010    6      1      1           12        23        56
2010    6      1      2           34        56        25
```

The result will be :

```
Year  Month  Group  Variable1  feature1_1  feature2_1  feature3_1  Variable2  feature1_2    feature2_2  feature3_2 
 2010    6      1      1           12        23        56               2           34           56       25
```

I am looking for something along these lines - any tips/help is much appreciated,

Thankyou

Izzy

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but `unstack` might be useful for you. It'll create hierarchical columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, if you want to convert it back from long to wide , you can using `cumcount` get the `addtional` key , then reshape.(Notice this reverse of `wide_to_long`)

```
df['New']=(df.groupby(['Year','Month','Group']).cumcount()+1).astype(str)
w=df.set_index(['Year','Month','Group','New']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
w.columns=pd.Index(w.columns).str.join('_')
w
Out[217]: 
                  Variable_1  feature1_1  feature2_1  feature3_1  Variable_2  \
Year Month Group                                                               
2010 6     1               1          12          23          56           2   
                  feature1_2  feature2_2  feature3_2  
Year Month Group                                      
2010 6     1              34          56          25
```